# Replace PHP code with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'd like to avoid the @elseif statement applying a regular expression instead. Tried some ways without any luck.

```
@if(request()->is('*backend/categories*')) active @elseif(request()->is('*backend/products*')) active @endif
```

Update:

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link @if(request()->is('*backend/categories*')) active @elseif(request()->is('*backend/products*')) active @endif">
```

Comment: I think you're going to have an if...else statement at some level no matter what. You use regex to extract the value you're looking for and it still goes though an if...else statement depending on what text was extracted via regex. Could use more context on what you're trying to do with the if...else statement.

Comment: This doesn't look like PHP to me.

Comment: This looks like Laravel. You could put the two `is()` in the same if. Could you show us the rest of the code?

Comment: Context: Trying to apply a CSS class based on the value of the current route.

Comment: @CBE https://github.com/laravelista/Ekko is a good package for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple patterns to `is`:

```
request()->is('*backend/categories*', '*backend/products*', ...)
```

Perhaps you want a helper function to remove the logic from the view:

```
function isActive($patterns, $class = 'active')
{
    return request()->is($patterns) ? $class : '';
}

class="... {{ isActive(['*backend/categories*', '*backend/products*']) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @azeós Thanks for your help.